# Update Job Application

Tags: feature-request, jobs

This might be an edge case, but if I apply for a job and change some details on my profile I'd like my attached resume to potentially reflect these changes. As it is now I can only view the application I made, but cannot update it.

Recently my official job title changed as they added in several levels. I'd much prefer people to know I've been performing as a II and to update my resume on those applications appropriately.

Comment: Congrats on getting the Tumbleweed for this one. I don't know why nobody looked. :)

Comment: Agreed. I don't think what I'm asking for is ridiculous or that complex.